# simplesamlphp behind ELB not working

Tags: simplesamlphp

i m running simplesamlphp behind AWS ELB. Running simplesamlphp on port 8888. Have configured ELB to listen on HTTPS which inturn listens to port 8888 in the instance.Unless I add some self-signed certificate  to the server the HTTPS doesn't work. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a specific configuration when you want to use ssl verification in the ELB and not in your instance. You have to use the header X-Forwarded-Proto set by the ELB. Read this both:

[ELB and Apache configuration for HTTPS website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17174626/elb-and-apache-configuration-for-https-website)

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/TerminologyandKeyConcepts.html#x-forwarded-headers